# Lenovo G780 and Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: boot

Just installed 13.04 on new G780, left UEFI enabled, but wiped Windows 8 off the disk.

Whenever I boot up 13.04, the screen shows purple for a few seconds, and then just the back light shows for a few more seconds, and then the screen goes black with no back light.

While it is booting, I have to press the Function key and hold it while I press the up arrow key, which increases the back light enough so I can see the Ubuntu splash screen.

When it is done booting I can increase the back light fully with the scale showing in the upper right corner.

Not a big problem, but just kind of annoying.

PS booting Ubuntu 12.10 worked great, but no wired internet.
Booting 12.04 worked the same as 13.04 with a black screen.

Formatted the 1TB disk with 5 partitions, 1=UEFI, 2=root, 3=var, 4=home, 5=swap

Answer (score 1):

Tried everything, finally had to **disable UEFI** and reload 13.04, **with option nomodeset**.

The only difference that I have noticed is that the driver listed in the details in settings now says Vesa: Intel etc.